# How to add another player to this snakes and ladders game

Tags: python, python-3.x

What needs adding to this code to make the second player work correctly.
Currently it asks for both players names, but only lets player one roll (ignoring player 2). There are no error codes.

I have tried adding duplicate code, but for the second player, however it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

The only thing that works for both players is asking for their names.

```
from tkinter import *

import tkinter.simpledialog

import threading


import random

dice_one_num=0
Snakes = [47,40,   39,34,   28,13]
Ladders = [3,8,   6,26,   14,22,   32,48]
player_one_pos=0
player_one_moves=0
player_one_bites=0
player_one_climb=0
player_one_name=""
player_two_name=""
def Move_One_Player():

    global player_one_pos
    global dice_one_num
    global player_one_moves
    global player_one_bites
    global player_one_climb
    global grid_one_array
    global PlayerOneMovesLabel
    global diceOneRollLabel

    if player_one_pos==49:
        player_one_pos=0
        player_one_moves=0
        player_one_pos=0
        grid_array[49-1].config(bg="white")

    old_player_one_pos=player_one_pos
    new_player_one_pos=player_one_pos+dice_one_num



    if new_player_one_pos>49:
        new_player_one_pos=49-(new_player_one_pos-49)

    for idx,val in enumerate(Snakes):

        if idx % 2 == 0:

            if new_player_one_pos==Snakes[idx]:

                new_player_one_pos=Snakes[idx+1]

                additional_message="Snake  |  "

    for idx,val in enumerate(Ladders):
        if idx % 2 == 0:
            if new_player_one_pos==Ladders[idx]:
                new_player_one_pos=Ladders[idx+1]
                additional_message="Ladder  |  "

    if old_player_one_pos>0:
        grid_array[old_player_one_pos-1].config(bg="white")

    grid_array[new_player_one_pos-1].config(bg="yellow")

    player_one_pos=new_player_one_pos
    player_one_moves=player_one_moves+1

    if player_one_pos ==49:
        PlayerOneMovesLabel['text'] = "Game won in " + str(player_one_moves)+ " moves"
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Game won", player_one_name+" won the game in "+str(player_one_moves))
    else:
        PlayerOneMovesLabel['text']= "Move: " + str(player_one_moves) 


def Move_Two_Player():

    global player_two_pos
    global dice_two_num
    global player_two_moves
    global player_two_bites
    global player_two_climb
    global grid_two_array
    global PlayerTwoMovesLabel
    global diceTwoRollLabel

    if player_two_pos==49:
        player_two_pos=0
        player_two_moves=0
        player_two_pos=0
        grid_array[49-1].config(bg="white")

    old_player_two_pos=player_two_pos
    new_player_two_pos=player_two_pos+dice_two_num


    if new_player_two_pos>49:
        new_player_two_pos=49-(new_player_two_pos-49)

    for idx,val in enumerate(Snakes):

        if idx % 2 == 0:

            if new_player_two_pos==Snakes[idx]:

                new_player_two_pos=Snakes[idx+1]

                additional_message="Snake  |  "

    for idx,val in enumerate(Ladders):
        if idx % 2 == 0:
            if new_player_two_pos==Ladders[idx]:
                new_player_two_pos=Ladders[idx+1]
                additional_message="Ladder  |  "

    if old_player_two_pos>0:
        grid_array[old_player_two_pos-1].config(bg="white")

    grid_array[new_player_two_pos-1].config(bg="yellow")

    player_two_pos=new_player_two_pos
    player_two_moves=player_two_moves+1

    if player_two_pos ==49:
        PlayerTwoMovesLabel['text'] = "Game won in " + str(player_two_moves)+ " moves"
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Game won", player_two_name+" won the game in "+str(player_two_moves))
    else:
        PlayerTwoMovesLabel['text']= "Move: " + str(player_two_moves) 

def rollonesDice():
    global dice_one_num
    global diceOneRollLabel
    dice_one_num=random.randint(1,6)+ random.randint(1,6)

    diceOneRollLabel['text']=player_one_name + " Rolled: " + str(dice_one_num)
    Move_One_Player()

def rolltwosDice():
    global dice_two_num
    global diceTwoRollLabel
    dice_two_num=random.randint(1,6)+ random.randint(1,6)

    diceTwoRollLabel['text']=player_two_name + " Rolled: " + str(dice_two_num)
    Move_two_Player()

def createGUI():
    global grid_array
    global PlayerOneMovesLabel
    global diceOneRollLabel
    global diceWindow
    global player_one_name
    global player_two_name

    diceWindow = Tk()

    diceWindow.title("Snakes and Ladders")
    diceWindow.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    diceWindow.config(bg='white')

    RevertLogoImage = Label(diceWindow, text="Snake and Ladders",bg='white',font=("Arial",20))
    RevertLogoImage.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=7)

    PlayerOneMovesLabel = Label(diceWindow, text="Please enter your name in popup window", bg='white')
    PlayerOneMovesLabel.grid(row=1,column=1,columnspan=5)

    PlayerTwoMovesLabel = Label(diceWindow, text="Please enter your name in popup window", bg='white')
    PlayerTwoMovesLabel.grid(row=1,column=1,columnspan=5)

    btnRoll = Button(diceWindow, text="Roll", command=rollonesDice or rolltwosDice, width=30)

    btnRoll.grid(row=103,column=1,columnspan=5)

    grid_array = []
    for y in range (0,7):
        for x in range (0,7):
            array_num=((x+1)+(y*7))
            grid_array.append(Label(diceWindow, borderwidth=8,text=  array_num  ))

            xx=x
            yy=y
            yy=abs(yy-7)
            if not yy % 2:
                xx=abs(xx-6)

            grid_array[array_num - 1].grid(row=  (yy+4),column=(xx+0))

            grid_array[array_num - 1].config(bg='white')

            if array_num in Snakes:

                if Snakes.index(array_num) % 2 == 0:

                    grid_array[array_num-1].config(fg="red")
                else:

                    grid_array[array_num-1].config(fg="red")

            if array_num in Ladders:

                if Ladders.index(array_num) % 2 == 0:

                    grid_array[array_num-1].config(fg="blue")
                else:
                    grid_array[array_num-1].config(fg="blue")

    while player_one_name=='' or player_one_name is None or not re.match("^[A-z]*$", player_one_name):
        player_one_name=tkinter.simpledialog.askstring("Player One Name","Please enter player one's name: ")
        if not re.match("^[A-z]*$", player_one_name):
            print("Error! Only letters A-Z allowed!")

    while player_two_name=='' or player_two_name is None or not re.match("^[A-z]*$", player_two_name):
        player_two_name=tkinter.simpledialog.askstring("Player Two Name","Please enter player two's name: ")
        if not re.match("^[A-z]*$", player_two_name):
            print("Error! Only letters A-Z allowed!") 
        PlayerOneMovesLabel['text']='- Waiting for first Roll -'
    diceOneRollLabel = Label(diceWindow, bg="white", text="Welcome "+player_one_name+", Please roll your dice!")
    diceOneRollLabel.grid(row=2,column=1,columnspan=10)
    diceWindow.mainloop()

createGUI()
```

Comment: Using globals the way you are is really sloppy and dangerous. You should be passing parameters and doing returns, not using this many globals. If you have to use that many globals, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two player snakes and ladders game - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45417209/two-player-snakes-and-ladders-game-python)